# Function not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

I have a function as following:

```
private long GetStakeholderId()
{
    string currentUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
    long stakeholderId;

    var users = _userManager.Users;
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        if (user.Email == currentUserId)
        {
            var idForStakeholder = user.Id;

            var stakeholders = _context.Stakeholders;
            foreach (var stakeholder in stakeholders)
            {
                if (stakeholder.IdentityId == idForStakeholder)
                {
                    stakeholderId=stakeholder.StakeholderId;
                    return stakeholderId;

                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }

            }

        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Here I am getting an error saying not all code paths return a value. What and where am I missing?

Comment: If it does not go into the for loop then how is it going to return. You need a return outside of the for loop

Comment: It hits no return when theres no users

Comment: Write  return 0; outside foreach loop

Comment: I disagree with the close voter btw, the question is definitely valid.

Answer (score 4):

The error is thrown because your function is not returning anything in the case you are not entering your `foreach` statement. As your function return a `long` value, you need to return in any case a value at the end of your function. I think the problem is that you misplaced your second return, which should be out of the `foreach` loop.

```
private long GetStakeholderId()
{
    string currentUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
    long stakeholderId;

    var users = _userManager.Users;
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        if (user.Email == currentUserId)
        {
            var idForStakeholder = user.Id;

            var stakeholders = _context.Stakeholders;
            foreach (var stakeholder in stakeholders)
            {
                if (stakeholder.IdentityId == idForStakeholder)
                {
                    stakeholderId=stakeholder.StakeholderId;
                    return stakeholderId;

                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }

            }

        }
    }
    return 0; // 0 will be returned in any case if you reach the end of the function
}
```

You might have to be careful with your current logic too. If the first stakeholder of your user is not the good one, you directly return 0, instead of checking the other ones. You might want to place your `return 0` only if none of the stakeholder ID correspond to the one you are looking for. Placing it there is fine, as you don't need to check for the other users anymore, and can directly exit the function.

```
private long GetStakeholderId()
{
    string currentUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
    long stakeholderId;

    var users = _userManager.Users;
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        if (user.Email == currentUserId)
        {
            var idForStakeholder = user.Id;

            var stakeholders = _context.Stakeholders;
            foreach (var stakeholder in stakeholders)
            {
                if (stakeholder.IdentityId == idForStakeholder)
                {
                    stakeholderId=stakeholder.StakeholderId;
                    return stakeholderId;

                }
            }

            return 0; // If none of the stakeholder ID correspond to the one you are looking for, it means it doesn't exist. You can return 0 directly there.
        }
    }
    return 0; // This part of code will be reached if the user is not found.
}
```

Comment: Well put, Isuka.

Comment: The foreach on the Stakeholder DbSet means you will do a `select * from stakeholder` on the database, you should not recommend doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Move the most outer return out of the loop. If the list of users is empty, the loop would never be entered. Then no return gets hit.

```
private long GetStakeholderId()
{
    string currentUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
    long stakeholderId;

    var users = _userManager.Users;
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        if (user.Email == currentUserId)
        {
            var idForStakeholder = user.Id;

            var stakeholders = _context.Stakeholders;
            foreach (var stakeholder in stakeholders)
            {
                if (stakeholder.IdentityId == idForStakeholder)
                {
                    stakeholderId=stakeholder.StakeholderId;
                    return stakeholderId;

                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }

            }

        }

    }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It might not enter the for-loop so change it to:

```
private long GetStakeholderId()
{
    string currentUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
    long stakeholderId;

    var users = _userManager.Users;
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        if (user.Email == currentUserId)
        {
            var idForStakeholder = user.Id;

            var stakeholders = _context.Stakeholders;
            foreach (var stakeholder in stakeholders)
            {
                if (stakeholder.IdentityId == idForStakeholder)
                {
                    stakeholderId=stakeholder.StakeholderId;
                    return stakeholderId;

                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }

            }

        }
        return 0;
    } 
    //Missing RETURN
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, the error is because you are missing a return in the case there are no users (so it does not enter the foreach loop). However, your function also has other errors:

- `if (user.Email == currentUserId) { } return 0;`

  - Here you are forcing that either the first user in the loop has the email you are looking for, or it will return 0
- `if (stakeholder.IdentityId == idForStakeholder) { } else return 0;`

  - Here you are forcing that either the first stakeholder has the Id you are looking for or it will return 0

Using LinQ, you can simplify your entire method to just this:

```
private long GetStakeholderId()
{
    string currentUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
    long stakeholderId;

    var user = _userManager.Users
        .Where(u => u.Email == currentUserId)
        .FirstOrDefault(); // get only the wanted user 
    if (user == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    var stakeholder = _context.Stakeholders
        .Where(s => s.StakeholderId == user.IdentityId)
        .FirstOrDefault(); // get only the wanted stakeholder from the database

    return stakeholder == null ? 0 : stakeholder.StakeholderId;
}
```

You should also beware that by using a `foreach` on a `DbSet` property means you are doing a `select * from table` on the database. You should use LinQ to filter the set in the database instead of doing it in-memoy.

Answer (score 2):

So many quick answers with same fix, But I have noticed a logical issues(Not sure is that an issue for your scenario) as well in the given code. What ever be the values in the variable `stakeholders` the loop will executes only once. that means if the condition `stakeholder.IdentityId == idForStakeholder` satisfies the method will return the corresponding id else it will return `0` and hence it skip executing the rest of values in the `stakeholders`(ignore this post if you are ok with skipping those values). If you wish to continue checking for all items in the collection then you can use the following code:

```
private long GetStakeholderId()
{
    string currentUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
    long stakeholderId = 0;

    var users = _userManager.Users;
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        if (user.Email == currentUserId)
        {
            var idForStakeholder = user.Id;    
            var stakeholders = _context.Stakeholders;
            foreach (var stakeholder in stakeholders)
            {
                if (stakeholder.IdentityId == idForStakeholder)
                {
                    stakeholderId=stakeholder.StakeholderId;
                    return stakeholderId;    
                }
            }

        }
    }    
  return stakeholderId;
}
```

Now this method will check for all values of stakeholders for all users, and will returns that `stakeholderId` which satisfies the condition (`stakeholder.IdentityId == idForStakeholder`) if any, else it will return `0` after all looping. And now you are free from that error as well. Please don't forget to initialize `stakeholderId` with `0` before start looping;

Comment: I guess this is a better solution as others were always returning 0 even if they found a match

Answer (score 1):

You should return a value as the error says, return the value outside the loop,

```
private long GetStakeholderId()
{
    string currentUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
    long stakeholderId;

    var users = _userManager.Users;
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        if (user.Email == currentUserId)
        {
            var idForStakeholder = user.Id;

            var stakeholders = _context.Stakeholders;
            foreach (var stakeholder in stakeholders)
            {
                if (stakeholder.IdentityId == idForStakeholder)
                {
                    stakeholderId=stakeholder.StakeholderId;
                    return stakeholderId;

                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }

            }

        }

    }

  return 0;
}
```